# Why is Entity Framework losing my indexes?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, indexing, entity-framework-migrations

When I use a database initializer like `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` or `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` to create my Entity Framework (5.0.0) database, the resulting schema does not include the indexes that I defined in my migrations, unlike when I create the database using `Update-Database`.

How can I configure the system so that it produces the same end result using a database initializer as it would when running the migrations in sequence?

**Example migration**

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateIndex("dbo.Users", "Username", unique:true);
}
```

**Result from `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` (*no index*)**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id]       BIGINT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Email]    NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

**Result from `Update-Database` (*includes index*)**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id]       BIGINT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Email]    NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Username]
    ON [dbo].[Users]([Username] ASC);
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have used is the "manual" code first migrations.  Where you get to fiddle with the script.  Automated migrations or drop create, EF just bangs a script together to match the table and Foreign keys and pops it out there. ie what you would have seen in the generated class before you added code. :-)

Use Automated Migrations/Create scenarios and just call SQL Command direct afterwards to add indexes from code. You have the SQL code to create indexes.  Just trigger the initializer and follow up with create Index custom routine.